# is possible call getLoaderManager().initLoader two times

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

i have a too complex query but  i can write the same complex query into two simples query

i want to do:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, new EntityLoader());
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, new EntityCounterLoader());
```

**is this posible in the same FragmentList?**

Comment: Why not ? But use different id's, not 0 for both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loaders can be initialized only once (i.e., subsequent calls to `initLoader` using the same id will not cause the loader to reload - for that you use [restartLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29)). However, as @user117 mentioned, you can have multiple loaders running concurrently and/oror within the same Activity/Fragment - they just need to have unique ids.